# free struct containing vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct

This is my struct containg vector:

```
typedef struct _player 
  {
    char                       id;
    char                       nick[30];
    std::vector<SOCKET>           mVector;
  } player, *PPER_player;

//allocating and freeing part

 lpplayer = (PPER_player) malloc(sizeof(player));
 lpplayer->mVector.push_back(socket1);
 lpplayer->mVector.push_back(socket2);
 ....
 free(lpplayer);
```

Is it enough to delete (with free) properly this struct **containing vector inside**?

edit:
example 2

```
typedef struct player 
  {
    char                       id;
    char                       nick[30];
    std::vector<SOCKET>           mVector;
  } player, *PPER_player;

//allocating and freeing part
  player * lpplayer = new player;
  lpplayer->mVector.push_back(socket1);
  lpplayer->mVector.push_back(socket2);
 ....
 delete lpplayer;
```

Comment: Your code is undefined behavior 'lpplayer = (PPER_player) malloc(sizeof(player))' due to  C allocation

Comment: Mixing C++ classes with `malloc`? Don't do it.

Comment: 'typedef struct _player' is another no good - just struct player in C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`free()` is **not** the same as `delete`. `free()` is a C standard library function and does not call the destructor of an object. (And `malloc()` does not call the constructor.)

You need to use `new` and `delete` here. And when you do, yes, `mVector` will also automatically be constructed and destructed, respectively.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it enough to delete (with free) properly this struct containing vector inside?

No. `vector` is a *non-trivial* type which must be created and destroyed properly, using its constructors and destructor. You can't simply allocate memory and pretend it contains one (although you can do that with *trivial* types like `char`). In general, there's almost never a good reason to use `malloc` and `free` in C++.

If you want to create one dynamically, you can use `new` and `delete` to create and destroy it correctly:

```
player * lpplayer = new player;
lpplayer->mVector.push_back(socket1);
...
delete lpplayer;
```

or, to avoid the hassle of deleting it correctly, use a smart pointer

```
std::unique_ptr<player> lpplayer(new player);
lpplayer->mVector.push_back(socket1);
...
// deleted automatically
```

or, if you don't have a good reason for dynamic allocation, use an automatic variable

```
player lpplayer;
lpplayer.mVector.push_back(socket1);
...
// destroyed automatically
```

There's also no need for the C-style `typedef` (which, in my opinion, is a bad idea even in C, especially if you use a reserved name like `_player` for the tag). Class names are usable as type names in C++, so just use a regular class definition:

```
struct player {
    ...
};
```

Comment: I edited my Question. Is second example ok? I mean , When i use New/Delete, I don't have to worry about that mVector is non-trival( and also changes its size with push_back before delete)?

Comment: @maciekm Yes, your second example is okay (I would still follow the suggestions in this answer about the `typedef` and so on.) As for the vector, the `std::vector` constructor and member functions will take care of allocating memory as needed, the same way it works if you declare a `std::vector` local variable. Nothing special is needed.